# AR.js: How to enable/disable camera and show/hide AR content on click of a button

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

All the examples and code that demonstrates AR.js AR capabilities over browser, works as soon as the web page is loaded. However, I would like to provide an option to the user, to manually start and stop the scanning process and the hide AR content.

Basically, I would like to load the a-frame, AR.js scripts and other a-frame html elements only when a uses clicks a button on a webpage.

Please let me know if there are any parameters in AR.js that can be passed to signal the user's intent to start the camera/scan/show our content.

---

Version of scripts:
A-Frame Version: 0.7.1 (Date 18-10-2017, Commit #b9a751e)
three Version: ^0.87.0
WebVR Polyfill Version: ^0.9.36

---

Answer (score 1):

since `ar.js` appends the camera feed to the `body` element, it's quite hard to contain it within a container on a typical website. I'd recommend:

1) Having a `ar` scene within in a external `.html` file, so you could place it inside an `<i-frame>`
2) When a button is clicked (or any other event) create the iframe, and place it on your website:

```
function addScene() {
  var scene = document.createElement("i-frame")
  scene.setAttribute("src", "ar.html")
  scene.setAttribute("height", "300")
  scene.setAttribute("width", "300")
  document.querySelector("#somecontainer").appendChild(scene)
}
```

Check it out on this [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-ar-onclick).